# Ghost.js deployment on Azure websites does not show icons properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, ghost-blog

I've been following the instruction on [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToInstallTheNodejsGhostBloggingSoftwareOnAzureWebsites.aspx) for how to deploy ghost.js from source to an Azure Website.  It mostly works, except the icons on the admin page show up as square boxes instead of the correct icon.

[image: Ghost.js admin page with square boxes instead of icons]

I enabled diagnostic logging according to the steps on [this page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-debug/) but didn't find anything that looked suspicious (no error messages or anything).

Any tips on how I can debug this?  I've tried following these steps multiple times, always with the same results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghost uses unicode characters for these icons. They are not images, they are rather normal unicode glyphs. If the font your browser is using by default doesn't have these glyphs it won't be able to display them. Some browsers will detect this (Firefox) and replace the glyphs from another font, while others (Chrome) might stick to the glyphs in the default font.

Try a different browser, and you should be able to see the icons, then change the font on your default browser.

**Update 1:**

Scott's instructions are missing a step. He asks you to comment the line in .gitignore that tells git to ignore checking in the CSS that gurnt just build in

```
# /core/client/assets/css
```

but you also need to comment the line under it to have git **include the fonts as well**

```
# /core/client/assets/fonts
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried opening the page on different browsers but it didn't work properly on any of them. If I install Ghost using the Azure Ghost web gallery template then the icons load just fine.  Do you know what's different between the template Ghost installation and what I'm getting when I try to deploy the default Azure source?

Comment: What operating system are you using? I am just tried the Azure template with Chrome 33 and IE 11 both on Windows 8.1 and both work and display the icons correctly

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. Ghost works perfectly if I use the Azure template. It only messes up when I try to deploy ghost manually from source using the instructions Scott Hanselman mentions on his blog http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToInstallTheNodejsGhostBloggingSoftwareOnAzureWebsites.aspx (it just takes a few minutes to run all the steps).  I'm also using Windows 8.1

Comment: ah Okay, I just tried that and hit the same issue as you. I updated the answer. Please let me know if that still doesn't work for you.